# How to speed up debugging of python programs in PyDev in Eclipse (esspecially Google App Engine)

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, optimization, pydev

How it possible to speed up debugging in PyDev in Eclipse for Google App Engine programs?

1. How to speed up code execution?
2. How to speed up application reloading?

Please share your experience or suggestions.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Webapp? Django? Web2py?

Answer (score 0):

How often do you need to reload the application?, the dev server will update all your code and  configuration changes without need to reload.

Comment: I need to reload application every time when program stopped on break point and I modify code is suspend mode - since it NOT RELOADS application at all. I use just eclipse + PyDev (same on two computers).

Do you have any idea why this code not reloads as should?